# I am getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable for the reccursive solution

Tags: python, recursion, typeerror

i was writing a reccursive solution to find the maximum element but i am getting a typeError at last return function in the code , can anyone tell me why?

```
def max(arr,i,size,max,index):
    if(i == len(arr) - 1):
       return index
    elif(arr[i] > max):
      return max(arr,i + 1,arr[i],i)
    return max(arr,i + 1,max,index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [2,1,3,9]
    print(max(arr,0,len(arr) - 1,arr[0],0))
```

Comment: You have a parameter in your min definition called max which is also a function you're using

Comment: i am getting the same error when even after than change @Sayse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a lot of bugs in your code

1. the name of your function was `max` and it also received an argument named `max` which caused the problem since when you try to call your function recursively your code thought you are "calling the argument" which is impossible since it's an int (by the way max isn't a good name since it is already used by python )
2. you sent an argument `size` to the function but never used it so I removed it
3. when your recursion got to the end of the array it returned the index (of the end of the array i.e the size) instead of returning the `max_val`
4. your recursion stopped when it got to `len(arr)-1` instead of `len(arr)` thus ignoring the last cell of the `arr`
   This should do the trick :

   ```
   def max(arr,i,max_val,index):
        if(i == len(arr)):
            return max_val
        elif(arr[i] > max_val):
            return max(arr,i + 1,arr[i],i)
        return max(arr,i + 1,max_val,index)
   ```

Comment: yeah , I had a unused size parameter because i needed to use it for an other recursive function to reduce the size of the array and find the maximum out of that .

Comment: that ok , you just forgot to send it to your recursive calls `max(arr,i + 1,max,index)` (here you send just 4 arguments instead of 5)

Comment: yes yes thank you , and additionally thank you for pointing out the last index , i didnt notice that the last cell was also skipped as i head was thinking about how the indexing ends at n - 1 .